# Android: Blocking keys from virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android

I want to allow the user to enter only certain characters to an EditText on a galaxy tab (Android 2.2) but block all other characters. An OnKeyListener seems not to react to the software keyboard.

PS: I dont want to block entire ranges of characters, like all digits or all special chars and so on. Let's say just the character 't'.

Please help. After an hour I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need the curiously and inconsistently named [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), and then call [`EditText.addTextChangedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) with it.

Comment: No, I need to block / delete certain characters. I think this is not possible with TextWatcher, because it will call itself recursively in an infinite loop or crash. I found an solution with InputFilters.

Comment: Its possible because I've done it. A custom InputFilter is probably better though.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this with a TextWatcher, you just need to be careful about when you make changes.

Comment: "Its possible because I've done it.": Ok... it would be nice to know how you've done it. ;-) My app crashed always.

Comment: How did it crash? Stack overflow (ho-ho) from recursion? Just use a boolean variable in your listener to skip processing if it's your listener modifying the text. But I think your InputFilter is a better way if you can get it to work... I forgot those things existed. :)

Comment: Yes, from recursion. I will use InputFilter, since it results in a cleaner code, I think (and it's working perfectly). Thank you. "I forgot those things existed.": do you never have to validate inputs or do you use another method?

Comment: I have used them once or twice for validation (of preferences IIRC) but it's not something I find myself doing a lot. I use TextWatcher more to know exactly when the text changed so I can update other parts of the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Call the onKeyDown event, and listen for the key that is pressed, if the key is one that is allowed, add it to your string, if it isnt, dont add it to the string. That, or strip the string after keydown of all invalid characters. Try http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0030.html for an answer on that. Thats java code, but I believe all of that carries over into android. Hope that helps

Comment: As far as I know this works with hard keys on the device only? I already tried this with the TextWatcher class and the code snippet from your link, but it ended in an infinite loop / app crash.