# Android - How to disable certain keys in virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard

How to disable certain keys (say number/symbol keys) in  Android virtual keyboard?

Specifically I want user can't input a double quote ( " ) character when virtual keyboard is showed up when user focus on a standard android EditText widget.

Comment: Use `TextWatcher` on the `EditText` instead.

Comment: use andoid:digits attributes : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929070/1012284

Comment: Hi check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806420/android-blocking-keys-from-virtual-keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to disable certain keys (say number/symbol keys) in Android virtual keyboard?

You can't, sorry. After all, the input method editor may not have "keys" in the first place.

> Specifically I want user can't input a double quote ( " ) character when virtual keyboard is showed up when user focus on a standard android EditText widget.

Then you will have to block the input at the `EditText`, by means of an `InputFilter`, as is described here: [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Comment: @Commonware, how do we disable the keys completely, i.e. the keys do not generate any key event at all. It just sits, there in the softkeyboard, as a disabled button.

Comment: In my note 2 device : my files> create folder> ; now go for special symbols and see; some of the symbols are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `android:inputType="..."` for your EditText

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: I think he talks about specific keys. Text but without ". He also talks about "standard" android, so he might be using already `inputType` defined `EditTexts`

Comment: yes, i use the attribute inputType, but i just can't find the suitable inputType that only for letters and numbers. But it's done now with edittext's attribute "android:digits"
Thank you anyway :-)