# Android - Graying out characters on keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to have an EditText element accept only 0's and 1's. I have specified its 'digits' attribute to:

```
android:digits="01"
```

This allows for only 0 and 1 to be entered, but I want to know if there is a way to 'grey-out' all of the keyboard buttons except for 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to your problem. [Android - How to disable certain keys in virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411608/android-how-to-disable-certain-keys-in-virtual-keyboard)

a work around might be just to create 0 and 1 buttons in your UI?